# Hosting html file over mosquitto

Tags: html, mqtt, mosquitto

I just found that mosquitto had got a websockets upgrade which allows it to 
host the HTTP services.

I tried hosting a html file using the websockets feature on the port 8080.

The mosquitto broker seems to start fine and the mqtt services on the other ports seem to function properly. But when i try to access the html file over the localhost I get the a response saying no data sent by the server.

I am not sure where my mistake lies..Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mosquitto is not a HTTP server, it can not serve generic files.

The HTTP listener is only there to facilitate an upgrade to the websocket protocol in order to run MQTT over a websocket connection.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers on how to make my browser act as a MQTT client which can subscribe/publish to topics?. What platforms can I use to achieve this?

Comment: If you want to ask something new start a new question, but I suggest you do some basic searching first

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look out for a different broker that is flexible enough to do what you're looking for. I don't know of any MQTT broker that allows you to do that out of the box, but many are fairly extensible. For one I can talk about is [VerneMQ](https://verne.mq), as I am one of the core developers. Developing a simple VerneMQ plugin that serves some static files over HTTP is a matter of a few lines of code, as the plugin only requires to setup some configuration for the internal webserver.

However, unfortunately we haven't yet documented this feature. But feel free to drop us a line if such an approach sounds interesting for you.

Cheers,

Andre